# Using methods to get and display userInput

Tags: java, object-oriented

Would like to know if I could have done anything better with the code that I wrote. Want to also know if I could have avoided using a static variable.

```
private static int numberEntered; 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int quit = 0;
    int sum = 0; 
    userPrompt(); 
    while(numberEntered != quit){
        sum += numberEntered;
        userPrompt(); 
        
    }
    printTotal(sum);
}
public static int userPrompt(){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.print("Enter number or 0 to quit: ");
    numberEntered = scanner.nextInt();
    return numberEntered; 
}
public static void printTotal(int total){
    System.out.println("The sum of all the entered numbers is: " + total);
}
```

Comment: basically I would also like to know if I can use the return value from the userPrompt() method as a condition in the loop and if so how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberEntered` should not be static and should not be a member.

It's good that you made a variable for `quit`, but it should be made `final` and probably pulled out to the class. It should be used for your prompt instead of the prompt hard-coding `0`.

You should not be re-instantiating a scanner on every call to `userPrompt`; store this as a member instead.

Consider using a simple stream to sum all of the numbers entered.

### Suggested

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    private static final int QUIT = 0;
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum = new Main().sum();
        System.out.printf("The sum of all the entered numbers is: %d%n", sum);
    }

    public int sum() {
        return IntStream
            .generate(this::userPrompt)
            .takeWhile(x -> x != QUIT)
            .sum();
    }

    private int userPrompt(){
        System.out.printf("Enter number or %d to quit: ", QUIT);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Enter number or 0 to quit: 1
Enter number or 0 to quit: 2
Enter number or 0 to quit: 3
Enter number or 0 to quit: 0
The sum of all the entered numbers is: 6
```